[Hono/Cloudflare]: Prisma Client DataClone Error
I'm using Hono and Prisma. The problem is that a new Prisma client is always created for every request. Consequently, parallel user requests are left hanging.
To tackle this, I found that durable objects could help persist the client object in a serverless environment.
The following is what I expect would store the Prisma client in-memory.
import { DurableObject } from "cloudflare:workers";
import { Pool } from "pg";
import { PrismaPg } from "@prisma/adapter-pg";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

type Env = {
  Bindings: {
    PRISMACONNECTION: DurableObjectNamespace<PrismaConnection>;
    WONDERCALL_R2: R2Bucket;
    APP_KV: KVNamespace;
  };
  Variables: {
    prisma: PrismaClient;
    prismaConnection: DurableObjectStub<PrismaConnection>;
  };
};

export default class PrismaConnection extends DurableObject {
  private prisma: PrismaClient | null;

  constructor(
    public state: DurableObjectState,
    env: Env
  ) {
    super(state, env);
    this.prisma = null;
  }

  async getPrismaClient(connectionString: string) {
    if (!this.prisma) {
      const pool = new Pool({
        connectionString,
        max: 20,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
      });
      const adapter = new PrismaPg(pool);
      this.prisma = new PrismaClient({ adapter });
    }
    return this.prisma;
  }
}

I am using middleware to retrieve the object.
const durablePrismaMiddleware = createMiddleware<Env>(async (c, next) => {
  const id = c.env.PRISMACONNECTION.idFromName("PrismaConnection");
  const prismaConnectionDO = c.env.PRISMACONNECTION.get(id);
  const connectionString = getDBURL(c);

  const prisma = (await prismaConnectionDO.getPrismaClient(
    connectionString
  )) as PrismaClient;

  await next();
});

// middleware
app.use("*", durablePrismaMiddleware);

But it gives back a Dataclone error.
DOMException {
  code: 25,
  name: 'DataCloneError',
  message: '#<t> could not be cloned."
}

What is the way out here? Any help would be appreciated. The end goal is to have a singleton Prisma client object so that it doesn't create a new one per request.
